# Is there a way for linux to read new adobe files with passwords?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I received a file from a business that needed me to enter a password.  It wouldn't unlock and I called him.  He said that I needed the latest version of Adobe. Apparently none of the pdf readers I have installed can read the latest password-protected file generated by Acrobat.  There doesn't seem to be an Acrobat for Linux any longer, or at least it isn't listed on the download list.  I attempted to load Acrobat reader for windows into wine, but it failed for some reason.

I'm running Mint Mate 19.

Is there any way I can read it on Linux?  I'd hate to have to buy a Windows system just for that.
Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you add information on which Linux distribution you are using? Depending on that, contributors may be able to suggest helpful tools.

Comment: here's a random link to try various tools: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/ . But if your document has an online method (requiring internet access) this wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Document Cloud (DC) hides inside a PDF file. The only way to access it on Linux that I'm aware of is to export(print to pdf) the file from Windows Adobe DC to a real PDF. DC has new online features that improve on the comical PDF DRM, but is really no longer a Portable Document Format (PDF).

Wine may work;
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32266

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Wine to run Adobe and exported a PDF that didn't require passwords.  I don't recall the details but it wasn't too hard.

Thanks,
Jim